# Checkbox value not changing from false to true when checked

Tags: javascript, forms, checkbox

This javascript function finds the errors in a form and lists them.  If there are errors, it creates an error override checkbox to allow submission even with errors.  At present the code does not recognize when the checkbox is checked.  Apparently the first if statement is always found to be true.  Ideas?

```
function check1()
{  
    // c_ierrors is the id of the input tag inserted below within the c_erros div

    if( document.getElementById("c_ierrors")==null || document.getElementById("c_ierrors").checked!="true" )
    {   
    //if javascript generated form error overide checkbox does not exist or exists but is not true then list errors and don't submit the form    
    //code to generate divs listing errors
    //
        if(error=="")
        {
            //submit form
            return true;
        }  
        else
        {
            error += "<div id=\"c_erow\"><input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"c_ierrors\" name=\"override\" value=\"y\" >Override Errors</div>"  //add checkbox to submit form despite errors
            document.getElementById("c_errors").innerHTML=error;
            alert (document.forms["cform"]["override"].checked);     
            return false;  //stay on page don't submit form 
        }
    }
    else
    {  
        //if override checkbox (exists) and is true
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the second part of the first if statement where you compare

```
document.getElementById("c_ierrors").checked!="true"
```

Comparing a boolean to a string gives you the wrong result. You can check this in your JavaScript console with,

```
bool_val = true
bool_val == "true"   # returns false
```

You either need to compare to `true` or just use it as a boolean value. E.g.

```
document.getElementById("c_ierrors").checked != true
```

or

```
!document.getElementById("c_ierrors").checked
```

Comment: Yes indeed thanks.  I was completely missing that even with many times going over the code.

Answer (score 1):

For finding if it's checked, you don't need to evaluate if it is true or not, especially with a String value.

You just need to find if it is `.checked`

If you want to find if it's not `.checked` just use:

```
!document.getElementById("c_ierrors").checked
```

Full code:

```
document.getElementById("c_ierrors")==null||document.getElementById("c_ierrors").checked
```

That will work just fine

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/szf7H/)

Comment: Thanks Christopher.  That approach would solve my problem and it also pointed out that I needed to test against the boolean true instead of string "true".